# How to count frequency of select values in Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, frequency

I have a dataframe with two columns, one for names and one for string values.
I'm trying to count frequency of select string values by names.

I've tried pandas.pivot_table and pandas.DataFrame.groupby but I'd like to create a whole new dataframe rather than aggregation.

For example, I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['John', 'x'], ['John', 'x'], ['John', 'x'], ['John', 'y'], ['John', 'y'], ['John', 'a'], 
                 ['Will', 'x'], ['Will', 'z']])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name','str_value'])
df
```

which results in:

```
   name      str_value
0  John              x
1  John              x
2  John              x
3  John              y
4  John              y
5  John              a
6  Will              x
7  Will              z
```

An expected result would be:

```
   name        x        y        z
0  John        3        2        0 
1  Will        1        0        1
```

and additionally:

```
   name        x        y        z
0  John     True     True    False 
1  Will     True    False     True
```

I'd like to select x, y, z only and return True or False based on whether the returned value is 0 or NaN.

Edit:
Thank you for the answers.
These work great, but the output has the subgroup "str_value":

```
str_value     x      y      z
name
John       True   True  False
Will       True  False   True
```

Is there a way to remove this so I have "name", "x", "y", "z" on the same level?
With .reset_index() I get:

```
str_value  name     x      y      z
0          John  True   True  False
1          Will  True  False   True
```

Is the name of my index "str_value" now? Can I rename or drop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.groupby(["name", "str_value"]).size().unstack()[['x', 'y', 'z']].gt(0)
```

**Explanations**:

1. Count the occurence per `name` and `str_value` with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html):

```
print(df.groupby(["name", "str_value"]).size())
# John  a            1
#       x            3
#       y            2
# Will  x            1
#       z            1
# dtype: int64
```

2. Unstack with [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
print(df.groupby(["name", "str_value"]).size().unstack())
# str_value    a    x    y    z
# name
# John       1.0  3.0  2.0  NaN
# Will       NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
```

3. Select desired columns:

```
print(df.groupby(["name", "str_value"]).size().unstack()[['x', 'y', 'z']])
# str_value    x    y    z
# name
# John       3.0  2.0  NaN
# Will       1.0  NaN  1.0
```

4. Compare values greater than 0 with [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html):

```
result = df.groupby(["name", "str_value"]).size().unstack()[['x', 'y', 'z']].gt(0)
print(result)
# str_value     x      y      z
# name
# John       True   True  False
# Will       True  False   True
```

Answer (score 2):

With a mix of `groupby` and `pivot`:

```python
total = df.groupby(["name", "str_value"]).size().reset_index(level=1, name="total")
counts = total.pivot(columns="str_value", values="total").fillna(0).drop(columns=["a"])
bools = counts > 0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

additionally to the other excellent answers you can use a mix of `groupby` `unstack` and `astype(bool)` for a one liner :

```
df1 = df.loc[df.str_value != 'a'] # remove a as requested.
df2 = df1.groupby(["name", "str_value"])["str_value"].count().unstack().fillna(False).astype(
bool)
print(df2)
    name    x   y   z
0   John    True    True    False
1   Will    True    False   True
```